# how to save seed to file awk

Tags: random, awk, srand

My teacher told me the only way to have random non-correlated numbers in awk between consecutive runs of the same script, is saving the last seed used to file and then read it again when you start another execution.

So far I'm trying with this:

```
BEGIN {
    getline seed < "myseed.txt";
    srand(seed);
    print rand();
    print rand();
    print srand() > "myseed.txt";
}
```

but the only content of `myseed.txt` is always 0 and I get the same random numbers at every execution.

Any ideas on how to save the status of the internal random number generator and then resuming generating random numbers exactly where it stopped between different executions of the same script?

Comment: Your teacher is wrong, see http://awk.info/?doc/tip/random.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about what the seed actually is.  It's a value used as a parameter to initialize the random number generator, and that's it; it does not contain the current state of the random number generator.  If you call `srand(N)` with any N, and then generate some random numbers, and then call `srand()` again (with any seed), the return value will be that original N, no matter how many random numbers you have generated in the meantime.

If the goal is to have a reproducible string of numbers, allowing for interruptions, then you need to save not only the seed but the number of random numbers generated so far since the seeding, and generate and discard that many at the start of the next run.  This is a terrible hack and you would probably be better implementing your own RNG or, more likely, using something other than awk.

If the goal is to make sure not to generate the same sequence even if run twice within a single second, then you should read the discussion at [the link Ed Morton posted in his comment](http://awk.info/?doc/tip/random.html).

Comment: I suggested that in a comment to my answer, but I doubt that anyone really wants to do that, especially for big `n`. Discarding lots of values just to arrive at the same state again seems like a really stupid approach, then it's better to implement your own RNG in `awk` and have direct access to the state which you can then save as you wish. I think the whole confusion stems from the fact that either the teacher has absolutely no clue about what they are talking about or the OP misunderstood the information given to him.

Comment: I tend to agree, @AdrianFrühwirth.  I mostly felt that the answers were missing an explicit explanation of the nature of the seed and the return value of srand().

Answer (score 1):

Either I misread your question or you are doing the complete opposite of what you are trying to achieve. If you read the seed from a file, use it, write the same seed back to the file for re-use the next time, you will always have the same seed, thus always produce the same run of numbers.

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{srand(1234);print rand()}' && sleep 1 && awk 'BEGIN{srand(1234);print rand()}'
0.240849
0.240849
```

If you don't provide a seed for `srand()` it will use seconds since epoch:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{srand();print rand()}' && sleep 1 && awk 'BEGIN{srand();print rand()}'
0.2776
0.668099
```

... thus it will only produce new numbers once a second. You can work around this by using `$RANDOM` (if your shell supports it; changes on each use) or nanoseconds since epoch (if your `date` supports it) as seed, e.g.:

```
$ awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}' && awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}'
0.661197
0.325718

$ awk -v seed="$(date +%N)" 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}' && awk -v seed="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(seed);print rand()}'
0.588395
0.911353
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to save to file the status of the random generator and reaload it later to resume generating numbers from the same point?

Comment: No, you cannot retrieve the internal state of the random number generator, but you could save `rand()` and use that as the seed for the next run (of course, that's not the same thing). But why would you like to do that in the first place?

Comment: What you could do is a) keep track of the number of times you call `rand()` and save that, and upon re-execution call `rand()` the same number of times but discard the values to arrive at the same state or b) implement your own [LCG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) in `awk`. But I wouldn't bother doing either.

Answer (score 1):

srand(seed) takes an integer value for "seed"

rand() returns a decimal number >= 0 and < 1.

So, saving the output of rand() to use directly as the next seed will result in srand() always using a seed of zero. Look (remember a call to srand() returns the PREVIOUS seed used):

```
$ awk -v s=0.1 'BEGIN{srand(s); print rand(); print srand()}'
0.566305
0
$ awk -v s=0.9 'BEGIN{srand(s); print rand(); print srand()}'
0.566305
0
```

So, if you want to use the output of rand() as the next seed you need to multiply it by whatever number you want your seed to be less than, e.g. 1,000,000:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{
    if ( (getline s < "myseed.txt") > 0 ) {
        print "seed read from file =", s
        srand(1000000*s)
    }
    else {
        print "using default seed of seconds since epoch"
        srand()
    }
    r = rand()
    print r > "myseed.txt"

    print "seed actually used by srand() was:", srand()
    print "rand() =", r
}'
using default seed of seconds since epoch
seed actually used by srand() was: 1368282525
rand() = 0.331514

$ awk 'BEGIN{
    if ( (getline s < "myseed.txt") > 0 ) {
        print "seed read from file =", s
        srand(1000000*s)
    }
    else {
        print "using default seed of seconds since epoch"
        srand()
    }
    r = rand()
    print r > "myseed.txt"

    print "seed actually used by srand() was:", srand()
    print "rand() =", r
}'
seed read from file = 0.331514
seed actually used by srand() was: 331514
rand() = 0.677688

$ awk 'BEGIN{
    if ( (getline s < "myseed.txt") > 0 ) {
        print "seed read from file =", s
        srand(1000000*s)
    }
    else {
        print "using default seed of seconds since epoch"
        srand()
    }
    r = rand()
    print r > "myseed.txt"

    print "seed actually used by srand() was:", srand()
    print "rand() =", r
}'
seed read from file = 0.677688
seed actually used by srand() was: 677688
rand() = 0.363388
```

On the first execution the file "myseed.txt" didn't exist.

Comment: I did not mean to use the output of `rand()` directly and unnormalized as input for `srand()`, but since this is not what the OP wants anyway (this is not equal to the internal state of the RNG and will thus start a new sequence of numbers, not continue from where it left off so I don't see the point in doing it) and quite an absurd thing to do I did not bother mentioning the detail, but good that you explain it nonetheless since it might not be obvious.

Comment: @AdrianFrühwirth - I wasn't even thinking about your post, I assumed the OPs teacher was telling him to save the last random number generated rather than the last seed used and he'd just misunderstood. I think this probably IS what the OP (or at least his teacher) wants and it is a fairly common approach.

Comment: Coincidence, then. I suggested exactly that in a comment to my answer, but he asked if it was possible to "resume generating numbers from the same point" which it is not with this approach. Can you give an example of when you would seed the next execution with a previous random number, rather than using a new seed? I don't see the point, unless this is solely to overcome the problem using seconds since epoch as seed and you don't have a better seed available at hand.

Comment: It's just one way to provide different seed values each time awk is called so you get different random numbers output each time around without relying on GNU date or other shell commands/constructs. This solution will work with any modern awk on any OS.